# Почему reduce не кладет элементы в список

Tags: javascript

```js
const example = ["1", "se", "thi", "four"].reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc = el + '!!!' + el.length + '!!!';
    return acc
  },
  []);
console.log(example);
```

На выходе у нас `four!!!4!!!`
Хотя я ожидал увидеть все измененные элементы в списке.
Насколько я понимаю

```
,
[]
```

именно вот этот участок кода отвечает за то, куда будут накапливаться результаты.
Я поставил список и ожидал, что измененные элементы окажутся там, почему их там нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) так не работает. Согласно документации:

**array.reduce(callback[, initialValue])**

**callback(accumulator, element)** - функция обратного вызова, которая принимает предыдущий результат `accumulator` и по очереди каждый элемент массива `element`.

**initialValue** - начальное значение для `accumulator`, если не задано, то оно равно первому элементу массива и в качестве element сразу передается второй элемент массива.

```js
[1,2,3].reduce((acc, el) => {
    console.log(acc, el)
    acc = el + '!!!';
    return acc
}, "это первое значение для accumulator");
```

Если вы хотели вернуть все в массиве, то нужно было их туда добавлять самостоятельно.

```js
const example = ["1", "se", "thi", "four"].reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc.push(el + '!!!' + el.length + '!!!');
    return acc
  },
  []);
console.log(example);
```

Или использовать Map для таких случаев.

```js
const example = ["1", "se", "thi", "four"].map((el) => {
    acc = el + '!!!' + el.length + '!!!';
    return acc
  });
console.log(example);
```